# jsonb_set deep nested update error occurs says No function matches the given name and argument types

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Get the nested object.

```
select jdoc -> 'members' ->'coach'  from api where id = 22;
```

returns :
{"id": 11, "name": "A dude"}

trying to update nested object, but failed.

```
update api set jdoc = jsonb_set(jdoc, '{members,coach,id}', 21) where id = 22;
```

Error:

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So where did I went wrong? jdoc column obviously is an jsonb column.
Manual reference: `select jsonb_set('[{"f1":1,"f2":null},2,null,3]'::jsonb, '{0,f1}', '[2,3,4]', false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter needs to be a JSONB value:

```
jsonb_set(jdoc, '{members,coach,id}', to_jsonb(21))
```

Comment: It works. jsonb_set(jdoc, '{members,coach,id}', '22'). I guess, for number add single quote will make it as jsonb value. For string. we need first double quote then single quote like  `'"string"'`. anyway, to_jsonb will make all these thing much easier.